# My variables from my include file are showing as undefined

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I'm trying to connect to an sql server, I have the connection information in a separate file, so then when I come to do the connection, I 'include' the file. I have done this many times and had many of projects working with this. I came to look at an older project and now my includes seem to have stopped working.

I created a new project and I'm still receiving the same error.

**Include File**

```
<?php
$serverName = "SE-APP01\\SE_DATABASE";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Stelram_SQLBE");
?>
```

**Project File**

```
<?php include 'db_conn.php';?>
<?php sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

In the project file, `$serverName` and `$connectionInfo` have red underlines and the error message reads "Undefined varianble ".

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When your issue isn't reproducible with the shown sample, then your sample code isn't representative of your real problem. Do not abstract code snippets in such cases. Also, 5¢ on scoping issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now is this:

```
<?php include 'db_conn.php';?>
<?php sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);?>
```

The problem is you have seperated te include  with the one you want to call a function. Try this:

```
<?php
    include 'db_conn.php';
    sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

Hopefully this resolves your error!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Still giving me the same errors.

Comment: Could you send me your file structure maybe it's an error with including the file.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and tested your code and found no problems.

In this case, I would only think that your db_conn.php was not loaded at all.

The first step I will suggest you try to enter the full path like:

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\your_site\db_conn.php';
```

or

```
include '/var/www/your_site/db_conn.php';
```

If you are lucky and the problem is solved, you can search and check your PHP settings in php.ini

```
include_path = "/var/www/your_site/db_conn.php"
```

If you don't have permission to modify php.ini, please refer to this page

[PHP Manual - set_include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)